# Could a 90 degree gentle bend reduce btu/hr flow by 25% in a natural gas connector?

Tags: dryer, gas, natural-gas

I want to connect my new gas dryer to my gas supply.  The 7.3 cubic foot dryer (DLG1502) came with a ½ OD connector kit that is not compatible with my 3/8 shut-off valve.   I bought a 3/8 connector cable that is rated at 28,300 btu/hr (I assume rating is for cable without any turns).  I could not find the exact btu/hr consumption for my dryer but some comparable dryers have consumption of less than 20,000.  Once installed, the cable will have a gentle 90 degree turn.

Could a 90 degree gentle bend reduce btu/hr flow by 25%?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why would you think it would? You bought a flexible hose (I think, you're calling it a cable...) and that's rated to be used as a flexible hose - which can have bends. The exact (or maximum, anyway) BTU/Hr for your dryer should be marked on its rating plate, usually located on the back near the gas connection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I read on another site that many factors can reduce pressure (length at a diameter, turns, material of pipe).  Given how hard it is for the manufacturer to imagine the number and type of bends that a flexible connector may experience, I assumed the rating is for no bends,but that is just my guess.